# android gradle increment lint

Tags: android, gradle, increment, lint

Since I would work on Android's increment Lint check, and I've looked at some articles, I found that I could add a task in build.gradle and then pass in some parameters by rewriting LintGradleClient, which should work as described in the article, But I follow the article described, in the increase the LintGradle parameter AndroidProject can not be got , where I use kotlin achieve.Someone who can help me?
Here is the article url path https://www.jianshu.com/p/4833a79e9396

My code in get AndroidProject as Kotlin:

```
fun getAndroidProject(): AndroidProject{
   var gradleConn = GradleConnector.newConnector()
   gradleConn.forProjectDirectory(getProject().getProjectDir())  
   var modelProject =   gradleConn.connect().getModel(com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject::class.java)
   return modelProject
}
```

and I run the task, it told me like this:

> No model of type 'AndroidProject' is available in this build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of android plugin in that article is old, the way to get `AndroidProject` has changed since 3.0.0.

After reading the source code of gradle android plugin, `com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask` gives a clue:

```
protected AndroidProject createAndroidProject(Project gradleProject) {
    String modelName = AndroidProject.class.getName();
    ToolingModelBuilder modelBuilder = this.toolingRegistry.getBuilder(modelName);

    assert modelBuilder != null;

    ExtraPropertiesExtension ext = gradleProject.getExtensions().getExtraProperties();
    ext.set("android.injected.build.model.only.versioned", Integer.toString(3));
    ext.set("android.injected.build.model.disable.src.download", Boolean.valueOf(true));

    AndroidProject var5;
    try {
        var5 = (AndroidProject)modelBuilder.buildAll(modelName, gradleProject);
    } finally {
        ext.set("android.injected.build.model.only.versioned", (Object)null);
        ext.set("android.injected.build.model.disable.src.download", (Object)null);
    }

    return var5;
}
```

Keep on track, we can find:
1. `toolingRegistry` is got by `GlobalScope.getToolingRegistry()`
2. `GlobalScope` is got by `VariantScope.getGlobalScope()`
3. `VariantScope` is got by `ApplicationVariant.getVariantData().getScope()`

The `ApplicationVariant` is the element of `applicationVariants` in `com.android.application` plugin, you can traverse the `applicationVariants` list to get it.

Here is the sample code in `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // other script...

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def globalScope = variant.variantData.scope.globalScope
        String modelName = AndroidProject.class.getName()
        ToolingModelBuilder modelBuilder = globalScope.toolingRegistry.getBuilder(modelName)
        AndroidProject androidProject = (AndroidProject) modelBuilder.buildAll(modelName, project)
        // create your task to do something
    }
}
```